# How to fix ffmpeg not being found | discord.py

Tags: ffmpeg, discord.py, voice

I've got a music bot set up using the discord.py github examples, and that all works. The issue is my ffmpeg.

When getting a bot to join, I receive the error:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: `Command raised an exception: ClientException: ffmpeg was not found.`.

I do have FFmpeg installed, the folder is in `C:\FFmpeg`.

Not too sure why it isn't finding my FFmpeg, so help is appreciated

Comment: Is ffmpeg on the path? Can you run ffmpeg by typing ffmpeg into the terminal?

Comment: Well, in my cmd (as administrator) `ffmpeg -version` gives me a result. It doesn't in my VSCode terminal, though

Comment: does it work in the CMD without administrator permissions?

Comment: Yes, it gives the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok turns out I just needed to restart my VSCode.. (im tired)